# Problems with date conversion in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a question, I'm trying to make an insert in the local database, in a table with a column with type datetime.

```
cmd.Connection = conn.conectar();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tab_item " +
    "values (@codVendedor, @codCleinte, @datavenda, @valorTotalVenda, @formapgmt)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codVendedor", codVendedor);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codCleinte", codCliente);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datavenda", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valorTotalVenda", valortotalvenda);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formapgmt", formadepagamento);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
mensagemretorno = "Sucesso para gerar venda";
```

This is the table structure in SQL:

```
create table tab_venda(
  id int primary key not null identity(1, 1), 
  cod_vendedor int not null foreign key (id) references tab_pessoa, 
  cod_cliente int not null foreign key (id) references tab_pessoa, 
  dta_venda datetime not null, 
  valor_total_venda decimal (18, 2) not null, 
  forma_pagamento int not null
)
```

The error I get is the

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Implicit casting from datetime data type to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Can someone help me? I don't know how to proceed with this insert

I tried to use a dateTime.Now, because I need the exact date to finalize the sale, but it still didn't work, I tried to force a convert of that value (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now)) to datetime but without success.

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now)` doesn't make any sense. `DateTime.Now` is already a DateTime.

Comment: You should list out the table columns in the insert to make sure the values match up.  `insert into tab_item(column1, ... , lastColumn) values(@column1Value, ... , @lastColumnValue)`

Comment: ^ This. You're currently using the `@datavenda` param to insert DateTime values into the `cod_cliente` column whose type is `int`.

Comment: As a side note, [don't use `AddWithValue()`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the columns, or else it will try to insert starting with the *first* column, which is the autoidentity `id` column in youe case:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tab_item " +
    "(cod_vendedor, cod_cliente, dta_venda, valor_total_venda, forma_pagamento) " +
    "values (@codVendedor, @codCleinte, @datavenda, @valorTotalVenda, @formapgmt)";
```

Also, there's no need to use `Convert.ToDateTime` on `DateTime.Now` - it's *already* a `DateTime`:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datavenda", DateTime.Now);
```

but I see from your question that you added it thinking that was the problem, so you can safely remove it.

Comment: Your opening statement is *not* true. If a table has an `IDENTITY` column then it is omitted when you don't define your columns in the `INSERT` clause (unless `INSERT_IDENTITY` has been enabled on the table in the current connection). Of course, this doesn't change the fact that omitting the columns is a bad habit. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g4Gmh27u)

Comment: If, however, `INSERT_IDENTITY` were on, the OP would not get the error that state: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xaP5HGVP)